# What type of memory does the "function/user_memory_bytes" from Google Cloud Metrics measures, physical or virtual?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm measuring the memory usage of my cloud functions using the *[function/user_memory_bytes](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-cloudfunctions)* metric from Google Cloud Metrics, but it's not evident to me what type of memory is being measured, is it physical or virtual memory?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the difference? You have the used and the allowed, but I don't understand that you name virtual and physical.

Comment: I'm writing a paper regarding this evaluation so I wanted to be more specific about it and not just call it "memory", but I guess it's not specified anywhere